# SSH2 (PHP ext) long command gets malformed. (escaping code issue?)

Tags: php, phpseclib, ssh2

**[1D** gets into long commands and break them. I have same issue in phpseclib and SSH2 PHP extension. Putty works without issue.

Here is SSH2 code:

```
    $stream = ssh2_shell($session, "vt100", null, 200, 25, SSH2_TERM_UNIT_CHARS);         
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);        
    usleep(500000);
    fwrite($stream, "enable\n");        
    usleep(500000);
    fwrite($stream, "mmi-mode enable\n");      
    usleep(500000);    
    fwrite($stream, "aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
    usleep(500000);
    fwrite($stream, "aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
    usleep(500000);
    fwrite($stream, "aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
    usleep(500000);
    fwrite($stream, "aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
    usleep(500000);
    fwrite($stream, "aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa \n");   //does not matter if i write command over multiple writes
    usleep(500000);
    echo nl2br(fread($stream, 8192));
    fclose($stream);
```

Response from server:

```
MA5683T>enable

MA5683T#mmi-mode enable

MA5683T#aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa [1Daa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa [1D
```

Added phpseclib code:

```
$ssh = new \phpseclib3\Net\SSH2($ip, 22, 1);

if (!$ssh->login($login, $password)) {
    throw new \Exception('Login failed');
}

$ssh->setTerminal("VT100");
$ssh->setWindowColumns(200);

$ssh->write("enable\n");
$ssh->write("mmi-mode enable\n");

$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa \n");
echo nl2br($ssh->read());
echo $ssh->getLog();
$ssh->disconnect();
```

Phpseclib output:

```
MA5683T>enable

MA5683T#mmi-mode enable

MA5683T#aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa [1Daa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa [1D
```

Phpseclib log:

```
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:07:65:6e:61:62:6c:65:0a     ........enable.

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:10:6d:6d:69:2d:6d:6f:64:65  ........mmi-mode
00000010  20:65:6e:61:62:6c:65:0a                           enable.

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:14:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61  ........aaaa aaa
00000010  61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20              a aaaa aaaa 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:14:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61  ........aaaa aaa
00000010  61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20              a aaaa aaaa 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:14:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61  ........aaaa aaa
00000010  61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20              a aaaa aaaa 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:14:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61  ........aaaa aaa
00000010  61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20              a aaaa aaaa 

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:01:00:00:00:15:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61  ........aaaa aaa
00000010  61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20:0a           a aaaa aaaa .

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.021, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:08                       .........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0005, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:04:0a:0d:0a:0d              ............


<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:0c:0d:0a:0d:0a:4d:41:35:36  ............MA56
00000010  38:33:54:3e                                      83T>

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0706, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6e                       ........n

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.009, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:61                       ........a

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0008, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:62                       ........b

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0093, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6c                       ........l

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0007, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0298, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:0c:0d:0a:0d:0a:4d:41:35:36  ............MA56
00000010  38:33:54:23                                      83T#

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6d                       ........m

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0095, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6d                       ........m

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0008, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:69                       ........i

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0092, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:2d                       ........-

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0007, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6d                       ........m

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0088, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6f                       ........o

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0007, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:64                       ........d

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0096, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.1, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:20                       ........ 

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0102, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0003, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6e                       ........n

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0266, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:61                       ........a

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0007, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:62                       ........b

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0035, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:6c                       ........l

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0007, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:01:65                       ........e

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0278, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:0c:0d:0a:0d:0a:4d:41:35:36  ............MA56
00000010  38:33:54:23                                      83T#

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0007, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:00:02:00:00:00:6d:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61  .......maaaa aaa
00000010  61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61  a aaaa aaaa aaaa
00000020  20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20   aaaa aaaa aaaa 
00000030  61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61  aaaa aaaa aaaa a
00000040  61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61  aaa aaaa aaaa aa
00000050  20:1b:5b:31:44:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61   .[1Daa aaaa aaa
00000060  61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61:20:61:61:61:61  a aaaa aaaa aaaa
00000070  20:1b:5b:31:44                                    .[1D
```

**[1D** occurs after 80 characters, which is default value of terminal columns. I tried to increase them, but it does not work.

Hex code of **[1D**: 1b5b3144

This is how it looks when i run actual command:

```
MA5683T(config-if-gpon-0/0)#ont add 0 sn-auth XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX omci ont-lineprof [1Dile-id 22 ont-srvprofile-id 0 desc "XXXXXXXXXXXX" [1D
Failure: The line profile does not exist
```

Parameter should be *ont-lineprofile-id* instead *ont-lineprof **[1D**ile-id*

What i am dong wrong? Can i somehow break command into multiple lines before **[1D** occurs?

Also i am using write instead ssh exec because it is losing connection in both phpseclib and SSH2.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your phpseclib code?

Comment: Phpseclib code and log added, i just removed from output and log login information.

Comment: The output doesn't look particularly big. That said, if you wanted to read up to `[1D` you could do `echo nl2br($ssh->read("\x1B[1D"));`

Comment: This is not reading error, it will break my commands and they will fail. I added actual command i am trying to run.

Comment: `"\x1B[1D"` isn't in the data you're sending to the server - it's in the data you're getting back. If you're confident that the issue is with what or how the data is being sent then why mention `"\x1B[1D"` at all since that isn't being sent? Anyway, even without that, you do seem to have some issues with your code. I'll detail on those issues in an answer (as opposed to a comment)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ssh = new \phpseclib3\Net\SSH2($ip, 22, 1);

if (!$ssh->login($login, $password)) {
    throw new \Exception('Login failed');
}

$ssh->setTerminal("VT100");
$ssh->setWindowColumns(200);

$ssh->write("enable\n");
$ssh->write("mmi-mode enable\n");

$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa \n");
echo nl2br($ssh->read());
echo $ssh->getLog();
$ssh->disconnect();
```

I'd rewrite that thusly:

```
$ssh = new \phpseclib3\Net\SSH2($ip, 22, 1);

if (!$ssh->login($login, $password)) {
    throw new \Exception('Login failed');
}

$ssh->setTerminal("VT100");
$ssh->setWindowColumns(200);

$ssh->read('MA5683T>');
$ssh->write("enable\n");
$ssh->read('MA5683T>');
$ssh->write("mmi-mode enable\n");


$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa ");
$ssh->write("aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa \n");
echo nl2br($ssh->read());
echo $ssh->getLog();
$ssh->disconnect();
```

Or something like that. I don't have a Huwaii device (I Google'd mmi-mode enable) but the fact that you're writing before you're reading is a bit of a code smell. https://phpseclib.com/docs/commands#gotcha-writing-without-first-reading elaborates.

Then the fact that you're sending another command before having gotten the output o the last command. Another code smell.

idk how `mmi-mode enable` is supposed to work. Does running that command put you into some sort of console where you can just type whatever and it's echo'd back to you?

https://phpseclib.com/docs/commands#determining-what-to-read-passwd talks about how to use `write` / `read` in more detail. Sure, that example is for `exec()` but the same basic principals apply.